# Gallery for art show

Tags: wordpress, gallery, tumblr, photo, squarespace

So, I need to create a photo gallery for a client. However, I do not have access to the code base yet (I know :/ ) and will not for a while. There's also nobody technical onsite, so they wouldn't be able to implement what I send them if I hand code the project. I was thinking of creating the gallery using something like WordPress/Tumblr/SquareSpace etc. and having them just link through their original site. I'm aware that there are a lot of issues concerning building this, but what do you think the best way to tackle this is?

Comment: what are you exactly asking? how to make a Wordpress website or how to add a link to their old website to Tumblr?

Comment: Well, how to add a link to their old site. But also, do you think that what I was suggesting (creating a gallery on one of the listed sites) is the best way to go since I don't have access to their code? I'm just looking for advice from somebody more experienced with this than I am.